# How to store data that includes callbacks

Tags: php, database, callback

There are, of course, many many ways to store a base of data. A database being the most obvious of them. But others include JSON, XML, and so on.

The probem I have with the project I'm working on right now is that the data being stored includes callback functions as part of the objects. Functions cannot be serialised, to my knowledge. So, what should I do?

Is it acceptable to store this data as a PHP file to be included? If so, should I create one big file with everything in, or divide it into separate files for each "row" of the database?

Are there any alternatives that may be better?

Comment: Are these user defined callbacks, or are they callbacks a developer will create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if they are created by the developer it should be easy to come up with a format... for example with JSON:

```
{
  "callback" : {
      "contextType": "instance", // or "static"
      "callable" : "phpFunctionName",
      "arguments" : [] 
   }
}
```

So then on models the would be able to use this feature you might do something like:

```
protected function invokeCallback($json, $context = null) {
   $data = json_decode($json, true);
   if(isset($data['callaback'])) {
      if($data['contextType'] == 'instance') {
         $context = is_object($context) ? $context : $this;
         $callable = array($context, $data['callable']);
      } else {
         // data[callable] is already the string function name or a array('class', 'staticMethod')
         $callable = $data['callable'];
      }

      if(is_callable($callable) {
         return call_user_func_array($callable, $data['arguments'];   
      } else {
         throw new Exception('Illegal callable');
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Theres some more error handling that needs to happen in there as well as some screening of the callables you want to allow but you get the idea.

Comment: So basically this calls a function that is defined elsewhere in code with the specified arguments and context? I guess that'd work, but I'm concerned by the fact that all the callbacks are anonymous, almost unique functions.

Comment: Ahh... i didnt realize they were anonymous functions. In that case maybe its better to think about storing serailized "events" in the datastor, then you can register your anon functions tot he events, just like you would in Node. A concrete example of the primary use case might get you some better ideas :-)

Comment: Accepted as best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how elaborate you callbacks are, for serializing you could wrap them in all in a class which utilizes some `__sleep` (create callback representation) & `__wakeup` (restore callback)  voodoo, with an `__invoke()` method calling the actual callback. Assuming you can reverse engineer / recreate those callbacks (i.e. object to point to is clear).... If not, you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Store names of callbacks instead, have a lookup table from names to functions, use `table.call(obj, name, ...)` or `table.apply(obj, name, ...)` to invoke. Do not have any code in the serialisable objects themselves. Since they are developer-created, there should be a limited inventory of them, they should be in code, and should not be serialised.

Alternately, make a prototype implementing the callbacks, and assign it to `obj.__proto__`. Kill the `obj.__proto__` just before you serialise - all the functions disappear. Restore it afterwards. Not sure if cross-browser compatible; I seem to have read something about `__proto__` not being accessible in some browsers *khminternetexploreroperakhm*

Comment: Ahum, php _cross-browser compatible_, `__proto__`? Are you sure you are talking the right language ? :)

Comment: Hehe. Yeah, that was kind of an understatement, wasn't it? :D